# Pandas create funneling based on user activity

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
user    created_at                    session_count     event_name
Alpha   2019-11-01 07:00:00+07:00     1                 A
Alpha   2019-11-01 07:00:01+07:00     1                 B
Alpha   2019-11-01 07:00:02+07:00     1                 C
Alpha   2019-11-01 07:00:03+07:00     2                 A
Alpha   2019-11-01 07:00:04+07:00     2                 C
Beta    2019-11-02 07:00:00+07:00     1                 A
Beta    2019-11-02 07:00:01+07:00     1                 B
Beta    2019-11-02 07:00:02+07:00     2                 D
Beta    2019-11-02 07:00:03+07:00     2                 C
Beta    2019-11-02 07:00:04+07:00     2                 E
...     ...                           ...               ...
```

The event name can be A to Z.

I want to make funneling like google analytics of user activity in same session but I have no idea how to do it. what in my mind is the function that has 1-4 parameters of an event that count unique user for example `funnel(A, B, C, D)`

and the result is

```
A    B    C    D
2    2    1    0
```

or `funnel(D, C, NULL, NULL)`

```
D    C
1    1
```

Feel free if you have better solution than me

Comment: How did you get the counts for those two funnel examples?  There's at least 1 D there for Beta and multiple Cs for Alpha if you're using `user`

Comment: @MarkMoretto it's funelling so D and C is pair in a session and it's means user click C after D

Answer (score 2):

In part, the approach proposed by Datanovice makes sense. **The bad thing is that in this way we have to modify the data frame every time we make a new query**. I think it is best that you **first obtain the data frame from which you want to obtain the information (and that you do only once)** and **use the function to make the query**.

```
count_df = df.pivot_table(index =['user','session_count'],
                          columns = 'event_name',
                          values = 'event_name',
                          aggfunc = 'size',
                          fill_value = 0)
print(count_df)
event_name           A  B  C  D  E
user  session_count               
Alpha 1              1  1  1  0  0
      2              1  0  1  0  0
Beta  1              1  1  0  0  0
      2              0  0  1  1  1
```

---

```
def get_counts_events(*args):
    return count_df[list(args)]
get_counts_events('A','B')
```

**Output**

```
event_name           A  B
user  session_count      
Alpha 1              1  1
      2              1  0
Beta  1              1  1
      2              0  0
```

**or if you want select specific user:**

```
def get_counts_events(user,*args):
    return count_df.loc[user,(list(args))]
get_counts_events('Alpha','A','B')
```

**Output**

```
event_name     A  B
session_count      
1              1  1
2              1  0
```

if you want to extract other features a solution is [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) (**this use Pandas >0.25.0**)

```
#if you need sort you can use other name like df_sort
#df = df.sort_values(['user','created_at','session_count'])
#count_df = df_sort.pivot_table(....)

count_df = (df.pivot_table(index =['user','session_count'],
                           columns = 'event_name',
                           values = 'event_name',
                           aggfunc = 'size',
                           fill_value = 0).add_prefix('count_'))


agg_df = (df.groupby(['user','session_count'])['event_name']
            .agg(first_event = 'first',
                 last_event = 'last',
                 count_events = 'count').join(count_df))
print(agg_df)

                    first_event last_event    count_events  count_A  count_B  \
user  session_count                                                            
Alpha 1                       A          C               3        1        1   
      2                       A          C               2        1        0   
Beta  1                       A          B               2        1        1   
      2                       D          E               3        0        0   

                     count_C  count_D  count_E  
user  session_count                             
Alpha 1                    1        0        0  
      2                    1        0        0  
Beta  1                    0        0        0  
      2                    1        1        1
```

---

**Function**

```
def get_feature_events(user,features):

    if not isinstance(features,list):
        cols = [features]
    else:
        cols = features

    return agg_df.loc[user,cols]
```

**Query**

```
print(get_feature_events(features = ['last_event','first_event','count_A'],
      user = 'Alpha'))
```

**Output**

```
              last_event first_event  count_A
session_count                                
1                      C           A        1
2                      C           A        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
def funnel_users(*args):

    new_df = (
    df.loc[df["event_name"].isin([x for x in args])]
    .groupby(["event_name"])["user"]
    .nunique()
    .to_frame()
    .T
    )
    return new_df
```

---

```
print(funnel_users('A'))

event_name  A
user        2
```

---

```
print(funnel_users('A','B','C','D'))
event_name  A  B  C  D
user        2  2  2  1
```

Comment: The problem here is that this operation is done every time you make a query, think that there can be many queries in a short time

Comment: @ansev you are right, and I would totally agree - your answer is much nicer, thanks for the explanation I learn a lot from you